# How to avoid italicised text following \sigma?

Tags: formatting, symbols, text

I am trying to include the symbol `\sigma` into a document of mine but I find that every time I use it, the text following it is in italics, e.g.

`\sigma{\textsubscript{\emph{x}}} is used to`

Produces:

[image]

Can anyone advise if I need to use a particular maths or symbols package? Or, more likely, what have I done wrong?

Comment: You would have had an _error message_ (the input should be `$\sigma_{x}$` probably. After an error message the actual typeset result is arbitary, just the result of tex trying to recover. Don't ignore error messages:-)

Comment: also don't use `\emph` (textual emphasis) to denote a math italic variable, the fonts and spacing are completely different.

Comment: There were no error messages that I could see. However, this has resolved the issue. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @MrMorgan Can you add a minimal example? If I try to reproduce your output I always get an error message.

Comment: Clearly it is generating an error, if your editor is hiding the error messages from you, reconfigure it so that it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The posted text produces the error message

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.8 a  \sigma
             {\textsubscript{\emph{x}}} is used to
?
```

Because `\sigma` is a math command so must be used in math mode.

`\textsubscript{\emph{x}}` would not itself be a tex error but it denotes a textual subscript and textual emphasis, both of which are entirely the wrong constructs for math.

So the solution is to do as the error message states and enter math mode with `$`

```
a $\sigma_{x}$ is used to
```